# kafka connector update rest api not update sink data

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am running a sink with wrong transform which produce wrong data in sink mysql table but when i correct sink configuration with `PUT` rest API and run it, it run successfully but not update existing data in sink table?

Answer (score 2):

If you data is not used by anyone then you can use following step:

1. stop sorce and sink connector,
2. clean data from kafka topic,
3. clean sink db data for particular topics,
4. delete( or rename) table history topic from kafka
5. change source connector name
6. start both connecctors.

Comment: Yes you are right but i already use kafka data and db data from source and sink.